# Simplify a Boolean Algebra expression with don't cares

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

In my homework assignment, I'm asked to simplify an expression of Q'RS'T' + Q'R'S'T + RS'T with don't-cares of m3, m12, and m14.

I know how I would achieve this result with a K-map, however the instructions of the question explicitly forbid the use of a K-map and only allow the use of boolean properties.

This means (or so I guess) that when the input (QRST) = (0011, 1100, 1110), the output can be anything. I don't see any identifying features of these that I could use to simplify it, again, without using a k-map.

How do I simplify an expression like this, while factoring in the don't-cares, without a k-map?

Comment: I would still draw a K-map and use that to write out the whole derivation.

Comment: I did that, and my answer was RS' + Q'R'T, which appears correct, however the furthest I can seem to get it using only identity simplification is QS'T + Q'R'T+RS' - WolframAlpha says this simplifies to what I got with my k-map, but I can't seem to simplify it any further.

Comment: How did you get the term $QS'T$? One of it's two parts, $QRS'T$ is in the expression, but $QR'S'T$ is neither in the expression nor in the don't cares.

Comment: I tried to derive an equation from the K-map (column by column) and ended up with (QR')'S'T + Q'R'ST + RS'T' - After simplifying that a bit by using DeMorgan's and distributing, I ended up with QS'T + Q'R'T+RS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The don't cares are $Q'R'ST, QRS'T', QRST'$. The expression to be simplified is $Q'RS'T' + Q'R'S'T + RS'T$.

$$\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|}
QR\backslash ST&00&01&11&10\\\hline
00&&1&X\\\hline
01&1&1\\\hline
11&X&1&&X\\\hline
10\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Adding $QRS'T'$ and $Q'R'ST$ to the expression,

$$\begin{align*}
f(Q,R,S,T) &= Q'RS'T' + Q'R'S'T + RS'T + QRS'T' + Q'R'ST\\
&=(Q'+Q)RS'T' + RS'T + Q'R'(S+S')T\\
&=RS'T' + RS'T + Q'R'T\\
&= RS' + Q'R'T
\end{align*}$$

---

From the comment expression,

$$\begin{align*}
g(Q,R,S,T) &= (QR')'S'T + Q'R'ST + RS'T'\\
&= (Q'+R)S'T + Q'R'ST + RS'T'\\
&= Q'S'T + RS'T + Q'R'ST + RS'T'\\
&= Q'(R+R')S'T + RS'T + Q'R'ST + RS'T'\\
&= Q'RS'T + Q'R'S'T + RS'T + Q'R'ST + RS'T'\\
&= Q'R'(S'+S)T + (Q'+1)RS'T + RS'T'\\
&= Q'R'T + RS'
\end{align*}$$

---

Maxterms:

$$\begin{align*}
h(Q,R,S,T) &= Q'RS'T' + Q'R'S'T + RS'T + QRS'T'\\
&=RS'+ Q'R'S'T'\\
&= S'(R+Q'R'T')\\
&= S'(R+R')(R+Q')(R+T')\\
&= S'(R+Q')(R+T')
\end{align*}$$

Comment: So to solve these, I essentially include the don't cares that I would normally group in when I write out my equation by OR'ing them onto the end?

A friend of mine said to go column-by-column on a K-map for these, so I did that. (Hence the comment expression)

Comment: OR'ing those terms is equivalent to making sure the function output is true when those terms are true. Column-by-column is possible as shown above, but you might have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The OR'ing of the don't cares seems much easier. I'll have to remember that method in the future. The wording of the question implied that I couldn't use a k-map at all, so I wasn't sure how to approach it, but now I see how the equations were derived. Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Still, the way of choosing the don't-cares is not trivial to me without using K-map, and so you may wish to keep asking others for better methods.

Comment: I'll ask my instructor, he never really specified how to do a problem like this.